# Should I get a reading across the discounted two terminals of buzzer (AT3840)

Tags: resistance

The buzzer is in a pest deterrent, the red light comes on but its totally ignored by passing cats. The sound frequency is not heard by humans so the only thing I can find suspect is the buzzer because it has no resistance across its terminals. I would be very grateful for your guidance, Thanks R Cook.

Comment: I am unsure about your question specifically but this might be able to help: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/103845/how-to-tell-a-piezo-buzzer-is-broken

Comment: By "no resistance" do you mean a SHORT?

Comment: Also, that "buzzer" looks like it needs a signal not just a voltage. Are you driving it that way?

Answer (score 1):

The AT3840 is a passive piezoelectric transducer it needs to be driven by a signal at its resonant frequency. A DC measurement across its terminals will show an open circuit.

Comment: Or it could be that cats are just stubborn.... LOL

Comment: @Trevor That did cross my mind :).